# How many font families are available for Google Font API?

Tags: html, css, api, fonts

I think the service is great but are these few the only fonts that are available:

http://code.google.com/webfonts

?

Or are there others and if so where can I see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently those are the only ones available.  You can host your own opentype font, however, using the following CSS.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Kabel;
   src: url("ItcKabel-Demi.otf") format("opentype");
}

h2{
    font-family: Kabel, "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```